# can't access webpage on docker container alpine base image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

Im not sure what i did wrong but i can't access the webpage from a running docker container alpine base image. The container is running but i get this error ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.Not sure if there is something that i needed to do in httpd.conf. I normally use ubuntu base image for my docker containers, but in this project i was asked to use alpine base. I am not use to alpine.

```html
FROM alpine:3.14

RUN apk update &&\
    apk upgrade &&\
    apk add apache2 php7$phpverx-apache2
 
RUN apk add --update-cache \
    php7-curl \
    php7-bz2 \
    php7-json \
    php7-mysqli \
    php7-xml \
    php7-zip \
    php7-apache2\
    php7-ftp \
    php7-xdebug \
    php7-mcrypt \
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-soap \
    php7-gmp \
    php7-pdo_odbc \
    php7-dom \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-zip \
    php7-mysqli \
    php7-pdo_pgsql \
    php7-bcmath \
    php7-gd \
    php7-odbc \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-gettext \
    php7-xml \
    php7-xmlreader \
    php7-xmlwriter \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-xmlrpc \
    php7-bz2 \
    php7-pdo_dblib \
    php7-curl \
    php7-ctype \
    php7-session \
    php7-redis \
    php7-exif \
    php7-intl \
    php7-fileinfo \
    php7-ldap \
    php7-apcu
 

# INSTALL COMPOSER

RUN apk add curl &&\
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php7 -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/localhost/htdocs
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:80/ || exit 1
```

```html
   webserver:
    image: client:2.0
    container_name: client
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - t_db
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier
    volumes:
        - alpine-www:/var/www/localhost/htdocs
  
    tty: true
```

Comment: Your container might be not working correctly. Are there any logs?

Comment: Can you also edit the question to include the image's Dockerfile?  That Compose fragment doesn't have any obvious problems, though it could be simplified significantly.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out apache wasn't starting. I've updated my dockerfile and added this line to it and it worked.

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `httpd:alpine` as the base image, thus you won't need to add the above line to your Dockerfile